# Store Binary Data in Vector

Tags: c++

I have the given class:

```
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(int capacity);
    ~Buffer();

    int size, capacity, client;
    int write(const char *data, int bytes);
    int read(char *data, int bytes);
    char *data_;
private:
    int beg_index_, end_index_, size_, capacity_;

};

Buffer::Buffer(int capacity) {
    beg_index_ = 0; 
    end_index_ = 0; 
    size_ = 0;      
    capacity_ = capacity;
    data_ = new char[capacity];
}

Buffer::~Buffer()
{
    delete[] data_;
}

int Buffer::write(const char *data, int bytes)
{
    if (bytes == 0) return 0;

    int capacity = capacity_;
    int bytes_to_write = std::min(bytes, capacity - size_);
    if (bytes_to_write <= capacity - end_index_)
    {

        memcpy(data_ + end_index_, data, bytes_to_write); //**ERROR
        end_index_ += bytes_to_write;
        if (end_index_ == capacity) end_index_ = 0;
    }
//(...)
```

I want to store the binary data in a vector, like this:

```
std::vector<Buffer> buffers_audio(2,Buffer(1000000));

void buffering_mem(char* chunk,int size_chunk, int close_file, int client, int total_size){
buffers_audio[client].write(chunk, size_chunk);
}
```

The `buffering_mem` is a function called from NodeJS and should store, individually the information from a few clients (sometimes, the function is called from client 1, sometimes from client 20).
But I am getting the error "Unhandled exception...Access violation writing location" in the memcpy. And I am not willing to copy the binary data. Anyone can explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: You are getting **what** error?

Comment: Side note: The buffer is not really circular (does not allow writing more than `capacity - end_index_` elements)

Comment: Unhandled exception...Access violation writing location

Comment: @DieterLücking yes..so far is not. But I want to be circular

Comment: size_ is not maintained. size_ and end_index_ are redundant (although you might need size_ while filling the buffer)

Comment: The vector *will* create copies of your class. As you don't have a user defined copy constructor, the default one will copy the `data_ ` pointer, but not allocate any new storage. After the first destrucor is run, any remaining copies will contain dangling pointers.

Comment: Rule of 0/3/5... Use something like `std::vector<char>` instead of `char *data_;`

Comment: Please write a proper test case.

Answer (score 1):

when this code is executed:

```
 std::vector<Buffer> buffers_audio(2,Buffer(1000000));
```

the following happens:

```
Buffer.ctor(int); //creates a default value on stack   
Buffer.ctor(const &Buffer) // initialize element #1    
Buffer.ctor(const &Buffer) // initialize element #2
Buffer.dtor(); // Destroy the temp instance.
```

Default copy constructor copies all Buffer's fields *including* `data_` pointer value. However, it does NOT clone the referenced data. In the result you end up with 3 object instances pointing to the same memory, which is most likely is not expected.

To fix it one can write a proper copy constructor. A simpler solution is to use vector to manage the data.  Additionally to reduce the number of object instantiations use `emplace_back()` .

```
class Buffer
{
 public:
    explicit Buffer(int capacity): data(capacity){ };
    char* data() {return data_.data();}
 private:
    std::vector<char> data_;
    ...
 };


std::vector<Buffer> buffers_audio();

buffers.emplace_back(100000); // call Buffer(int) in-place
buffers.emplace_back(100000);
```